# Ubuntu - EFI variables are not supported on this system

Tags: command-line, 16.04, sudo

I'm trying to run `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` and `sudo mokutil --import MOK.der` But, I get this message in Command line:

> EFI variables are not supported on this system

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   4.7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  82.9G  0 part /media/ali/8593EB75DEE9C7C1
└─sda6   8:6    0 145.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /media/ali/Local Disk
```

What is that?

How can the problem be solved?

**Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS.**

Comment: you have installed ubuntu in UEFI, right?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I do not know about it!

Comment: can you quickly run `lsblk` and update the question with resulting out put.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Updated.

Comment: there is a `1k partition` i'm not sure if it's EFI, maybe other some other user will be able to help

Comment: Does `/boot` contain an EFI directory?

Comment: @muru No, It not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to compile a kernel module in a Virtualbox guest machine (Ubuntu 16.04). In this case, the `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG` kernel config option requires kernel modules to be signed. However, UEFI and, thus, Secure Boot are not available so you can't actually sign the module. And as you noticed, disabling the validation doesn't work either.

In this case, the only solution that worked for me was to recompile the kernel following the instructions at [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). These instructions worked for me as they were with the only exception that I also had to install `libncurses5` and `libncurses5-dev` via apt.

When changing the configuration options with `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs`, disable the `Module signature verification` option in the `Enable Loadable Module Support` section. I did that for every single arch/flavor, which might or might not be necessary.

This approach worked for me, and if you don't screw up too much (as I did...), it should be done within 30 minutes (plus compile time, which depends heavily on your system). Note, however, that compiling the kernel took around 15 GB of disk space for me. Also, make sure to hold your kernel packages later so you don't accidentally upgrade your kernel (you will have to repeat the procedure for each new kernel version).

Comment: this idea will work but industrial perspective, it is not viable. One should you signing the module and resolve the issue. Go through this step by step guide [signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel#generating-a-public-and-private-key-pair_signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot)